# Does WebLogic Topic guarantee the delivery over Queue?

Tags: jakarta-ee, queue, jms, weblogic12c, jms-topic

We are experiencing message lost between source and destination which are delivered over Queues. Both Source and Destination applications are deployed in two different WebLogic cluster instances.

We have enabled file store for message persistence as well but still we have noticed that some of the messages are not consumed from the destination Queue.

One of the solution proposed, is to create a Topic and listen through a single Queue from the destination application assuming guaranteed message delivery. I'm not convinced as I still see a possibility of loosing messages except that it will guarantee at least message is consumed by the configured consumer once if we use a Topic.

Appreciate your thoughts of enabling guaranteed message delivery.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to understand is that **"guaranteed delivery" is neither the criteria to choose between JMS queue and topic not the difference between queue and topic**. There are many other criteria's and difference between queue and topic like you would choose queue over topic because of load balancing reasons, a message sent to a queue would be sent to one the consumers of the queue while a message sent to a topic would be sent to all consumers of the topic (except in case of distributed partitioned topic), so that's how in case of queue, message is load balanced between several queue consumers.

Now, I am making a basic assumption here that you understand that suppose you have a queue Q1 which has 3 queue consumers - QC1, QC2 and QC3, now when a message is sent to Q1 then this message would be delivered to either of the consumers QC1 or QC2 or QC3, it wouldn't be delivered to more than 1 queue consumer. So, considering this I am again assuming that when you say your messages are lost then you don't mean that QC1 didn't receive the message (because it might have got delivered to QC2 or QC3, as expected). If my assumptions are wrong then it means your understanding on JMS queue is not correct and hence the behavior you are getting is expected.

Now, with core concepts in place, if, now,  the behavior you are getting is expected then using a JMS topic is right solution because in case of JMS topic, a message would be delivered to all topic subscribers. So, suppose you have a JMS topic T1 which has 3 topic subscribers - TS1, TS2 and TS3, when the message is sent to T1 then this message would be delivered to all 3 topic subscribers.

Now, still if you see your messages are getting lost, then you have to check whether this is happening with only some message or all messages, if it is with all messages then it is quite probable that your code is not correct for consuming/subscribing, and if it is happening with only some messages then you to think if it could be some network issue.

---

**Update:** Based on OP's input it is clear that OP's JMS setup is working fine and migrating to topic wouldn't help, now there is no solution as such and it is about debugging the issue, below are my thoughts:

- You have to debug from n/w perspective that whether messages are getting lost between JMS producer to JMS provider or JMS provider and JMS consumer. I am guessing that it is getting lost between JMS producer and JMS provider because if it was getting lost between JMS provider and JMS consumer then JMS provider would have never got the acknowledgment and hence would have the messages in its queue. You can check whether those messages are still in JMS provider queue or not, for that you can use "queue browser", if messages are not in queue then it means it is getting lost between JMS producer and JMS provider.
- Is there anything different for those messages, probably some JMS header or something.

Comment: thank you very much for your prompt response. Messages received in Q1 are rightly expected to consume only by one of the consumers out configured queues and in this case one of QC1, QC2 or QC3. 99% this is happening and we have noticed that rarely some of the messages are not consumed by any of the consumers. we are processing hundred thousand messages daily if i'm to give you some context of the volume.

Comment: Ok. So like I said then it means that there could be some network issue, your setup is working fine, and you are right that navigating to topic wouldn't help either. Read my updated answer for my debugging thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before, but to be honest: it was never the fault of the JMS topic/queue setup: Given that the system is running continuously (not crashing) and the JMS resources are also running ok (file store or database are not full) then this behaviour can be observed if *one* message handler is picking messages that it does not handle (it ignores them):

Not sure how your message handlers looks like, but if it has a concept of "identifying" messages by type in a switch-case or delegating them by type, it could be it picks messages that it doesn't know. This can have two basic reasons:

1) You forgot in (one!) of the handlers to have that lost message type being handled. Mostly check for a rather innocent looking handler :-).

2) Your sender/receiver code does not match and thus a "instanceof" fails due to inconsistencies (I have seen that more than once): check if your code uses the exact same types on both ends.